# java server socket programming returning null value to client

Tags: java, sockets, server

I'm using java as server. I used a java client. The server will accept data from client.That part works fine. But returning value to client is showing null.i'm pretty sure my client side programs work fine. my server side program is

```
package server;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class doing {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket s1= new ServerSocket(5000);
        ServerSocket s2= new ServerSocket(6000);
        while(true) {
            Socket s=null;
            s=s1.accept();
            System.out.println("A new client is connected :");
            BufferedReader br = null;
            System.out.println("Threading : \n");
            recieve some=new recieve(s2, br);
            Thread t= new Thread(some);
            t.start();
            try {
                t.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String val=some.gett();
            sended go=new sended(s2,val);
            Thread t2=new Thread(go);
            t2.start();
            s.close();
        }
    }


}
class sending extends Thread{
    ServerSocket s1;
    Socket s=null;
    BufferedWriter bw;
    String val="";
    public sending(ServerSocket s1, String val) {
        this.s1=s1;
        this.val=val;
    }
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("writing : ");
                try {
                    s=s1.accept();
                    bw=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
                    bw.write(val);
                    System.out.println("sended : \n");
                    s.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    }
}
class recieve implements Runnable{
    ServerSocket s1;
    Socket s=null;
    BufferedReader br;
    private volatile String val="";
    public recieve(ServerSocket s1,BufferedReader br) {
        this.br = br;
        this.s1=s1;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            s=s1.accept();
            br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            val=br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Recieved : ");
            System.out.println(val);
            s.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public String gett() {
        return val;

    }


}
class sended implements Runnable{
    ServerSocket s1;
    Socket s=null;
    BufferedWriter bw;
    String val="";
    public sended(ServerSocket s1, String val) {
        this.s1=s1;
        this.val=val;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("writing : ");
        try {
            s=s1.accept();
            bw=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
            bw.write(val);
            System.out.println("sended : \n");
            s.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

the returned value is null for every client. i used different client programs. I'm stuck here and been spending a lot time. (i've even used 3 different serversockets for connection,sending and recieve but recieving shows null value)
my client program is

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class clie {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        Socket ss = new Socket("192.168.0.103",5000);
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        String num=sc.next();
        ss.close();
        ss= new Socket("192.168.0.103",6000);
        PrintStream p= new PrintStream(ss.getOutputStream());
        p.print(num);
        ss.close();
        ss= new Socket("192.168.0.103",6000);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ss.getInputStream()));
        String rec=br.readLine();
        System.out.print(rec);
        ss.close();
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Close the buffered writer, not the socket. You only need one server socket and one client socket. You are doing three accepts and three connects, where you only need one of each, and you aren't doing anything with the first accepted socket and the first client socket. Null means end of stream. It is not a value received from the server. Too many errors here. You need to read a networking tutorial. See the Custom Netwroking section of the Java Tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Ummm... you can't read on one socket and write to another and expect your client to magically connect to the second socket just because you opened it on the server. There's a whole process of negotiating/opening a connection, sending a request, waiting/receiving a response, and then closing the connection.

You are reading from ss (at port 5000) then re-initializing ss to be on port 6000 but you connected client doesn't know this. The client connected on port 5000 and sent a request but never got a response on port 5000. In fact your client will see port 5000 as being closed before it sent a response so the response is indeed null.

I think you have some misconceptions about socket-communications... I'd suggest reading up on how the request-response lifecycle works in socket-communications...

Comment: @craterlee Just using one socket works for everybody. The entire Web works that way. You did it wrong. That is what you should be asking about, not this mess.

Comment: The client didn't actualy do anything with the connection on oort 5000. It is therefore a complete waste of time.